# Does there exist a nonmeasurable function on [a,b]?

Tags: measure-theory

I know if for all $r\in R$, {x|f(x)>r} is a measurable set, f is a measurable (f:[a,b]$\to$ R).

Does there exist a nonmeasurable function on [a,b]?

Comment: Yes, the indicator function of a non-measurable set can't be measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably have already seen a proof (using the Axiom of Choice) that $[a,b]$ has a non-measurable subset $K$. For $x\in [a,b]$, let $f(x)=1$ if $x\in K$, and let $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Let $r=0$. The set of $x$ such that $f(x)\gt r$ is not measurable.

Comment: excuse me, I am confused. A theorem is {x|f(x)>r} and {x|f(x)$\ge$r} and {x|f(x)<r} and {x|f(x)$\le$r} are hold. And I thought the Indicator function (your example) satisfies {f(x)$\ge$ r}

Comment: The set of $x$ such that $f(x)\gt 0$ is (in this case) the set of $x$ such that $f(x)=1$, which is $K$. If you prefer we can use $r=1/2$.

Comment: @user140744: Your first sentence should be *if and only if*.